# Are Schiphol airport hotels noisy?

Tags: hotels, amsterdam

We are visiting Amsterdam for 2 nights and will try to stay somewhere near Schiphol (if possible) to catch the 10 A.M. flight.

We can see quite a lot of marquee hotels near Schiphol with good weekend rates, but couldn't imagine how the noise level would be. A good night's sleep can beat anything, as long as we can get it. Does anyone have any experience staying near Schiphol? Do we need to seek Air BNB for saving ourselves some hassle?

Comment: Note that Schiphol has excellent frequent rail connections to Amsterdam, so the difference in travel time between "near Schiphol [but not one of the airport hotels]" and staying in the city may be fairly minimal. It might still be cheaper and easier for you though, so still worth considering.

Comment: It definitely saves a lot of time and stress to stay in a hotel airside.

Comment: The first thing on my holiday pack list is "earplugs". Always have earplugs and spares with you and life on the road has one less worry.

Comment: I have missed a flight and stayed Ibis Schiphol Amsterdam Airport in December 2017, I didn't notice any problems.. breakfast was great and hotel shuffles from the airport are frequent - yet I'm not sure it's a fair comparison because IMHO when you are tired from the flight you are more likely to fall asleep faster.

Comment: The title edit has make some answers less relevant (basically invalidating them); and does not appear to be the exact intent of what the OP is asking (I'd say the question is what are good options for a noise- & hassle-free stay at or around Schiphol).

Answer (score 26):

I have slept more times in the Yotel *inside* Schiphol than I would want to admit. It's very very quiet.

You really can't beat an inside-an-airport hotel in terms of time to shower and bed after a zombie like shuffle off a transoceanic flight. It's bliss. And at Schiphol you are already inside security (!) so you don't need to guess the right time to leave your hotel. Not even the Gatwick or Heathrow Yotels are airside, nonetheless they are quite awesome especially the Gatwick one, the Heathrow one is in a far away terminal I somehow never land or leave from (uh, can you tell I have been to both... once or twice ;) ?). There should be more capsule hotels airside, really.

Edit: oh, Yotel agrees and they are expanding! After too long, now there's one at Paris Charles De Gaulle (CDG) airport -- and it's airside, too although more restricted than the one at Schiphol due to the way the airport is laid out.

Comment: If it's inside the secure zone, does this mean you have to go through the airport security every time you go to the city?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Yotel is super expensive for a cabin, but looks good though (colourful and all) - my gf will disagree :)

Comment: This reads more like an advertisement for Yotel than an answer.

Comment: What can I do? Yotel is awesome.

Comment: @IMil that defeats the purpose.  You would only stay at a Yotel in the hours prior to a departure.  All other days get a cheaper better hotel nearer where you want to be.  You wouldn't want to fight through security just to get back to your hotel room, and security wouldn't want you doing that either.

Comment: I think the crazy Yotel bed made my neck hurt, but that could just be my sleeping style.

Comment: I am always carrying my own tempur travel neck pillow (I am apparently a spam machine here) so I can't comment on that, I take care of my own spine.

Comment: If the OP wants to sleep in Yotel to catch a morning flight, one would like to check in baggage the evening before: that is not always possible. And one can't get through security without a valid boarding pass either, so this option is not very practical for everyone.

Comment: Yotel is great if what you want is a ultrabasic suspended animation pod inside the airport. If you want to do anything but sleep and shower, then they're not for you. I've stayed at the one at Gatwick, and it's basically racks of pods in the basement. Quite comfortable, and the location couldn't be more convenient, but you don't even get a window. (Actually, at Gatwick, I'd recommend the Bloc instead. Similar prices, same location, but much more civilised.) Also the Yotel breakfast is a basically an airline breakfast tray in a cardboard box. Forget it and go to an airport cafe instead.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest checking multiple reviews for any hotels you are considering. Good soundproofing is a key feature for modern airport hotels. If guests could not sleep because of noise it would be a very prominent complaint.

If you do go Air BNB make sure you are well away from the airport and not on any major flight path. You cannot necessarily expect a house or apartment building to have as good soundproofing as a marquee airport hotel.

Comment: Thanks trying to find something near Osdorp and DE Punt - seems like a good area.

Comment: @hagubear: As a local, you may also consider anything close to the Zuid station. There are trains from Zuid to Schipol every 10 minutes or so, and it takes less than 5/10 min to actually get to the airport (no stop in between), arriving straight in the middle of it (it's an underground station, under the center of the building). Aim North of Zuid (flights pass South of it), and you won't have to worry about noise levels at all.

Comment: @MatthieuM.       Gotta say - Zuid looks good. But very pricey as of today. Hoping for a miracle :)

Answer (score 10):

In April 2013 I stayed at the Schiphol Airport Sheraton, which is attached to the main terminal building and an easy walk to check in and the gates. I was in a mid-level room. It was very very quiet and I was able to sleep well there.

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to promote [Zach Lipton's comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98044/schiphol-airport-hotel-noise-level-any-idea-suggestions#comment233879_98044) to an answer.

Amsterdam proper *is* near Schiphol - about a 20min train ride from the airport station to the main Amsterdam station, with trains running regularly. No problem at all bringing luggage on the train, and at the airport you can get a multi-day pass for unlimited train rides (includes other forms of transportation as well).

In Amsterdam, assuming you choose a "good" hotel, it should be as quiet as one could reasonably expect in a city.

Comment: Just to expand on this - it depends where in Amsterdam you pick the hotel; if it on the main streets then you'll be okay, something in the back streets and you have to deal with the nightlife - and if you are really unlucky, you might end up with one next to a church with the bell tolling :-/

Comment: Try Area like Sloterdijk too, cheap and quite and trains to Airport too

Answer (score 3):

As yours is a common problem, *most* on-airport hotels in developed countries have very good soundproofing, as do many of the reputable brands in their near-airport hotels.  So I suggest that you initially choose your hotel on price and location, then check reviews and their own website before booking, for noise but also for anything else that puts you off (one related example of the latter: room temperature control.  Because the windows have to be sealed against noise, you have to rely on the air conditioning/heating, which can very from pathetic through noisy to fierce)

Answer (score 2):

Writing about your situation rather than your specific question:

Schiphol is very well connected by train, and some hotels are close enough to train stations to make it worthwhile to also consider them instead of proper at-airport hotels. I just made a random query on [some website](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaKkBiAEBmAEuwgEDeDExyAEP2AEB6AEB-AELkgIBeagCAw&lang=en-gb&sid=1300a1428d6c6d6ab82233aac3b3705f&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaKkBiAEBmAEuwgEDeDExyAEP2AEB6AEB-AELkgIBeagCAw%3Bsid%3D1300a1428d6c6d6ab82233aac3b3705f%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Amsterdam%2C%20Noord-Holland%2C%20Netherlands&ssne=Kassel&ssne_untouched=Kassel&checkin_monthday=4&checkin_month=1&checkin_year=2018&checkout_monthday=5&checkout_month=1&checkout_year=2018&sb_travel_purpose=business&room1=A&no_rooms=2&group_adults=1&group_children=0&ss_raw=amsterdam&ac_position=0&ac_langcode=en&dest_id=-2140479&dest_type=city&search_pageview_id=e19b781ea7e3003b&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=e19b781ea7e3003b&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0#map_closed) - if you go there and click on the map view you'll notice several options close to train stations. You should not have a problem getting to the airport on time for your flight (and having enough time to sleep).

I will say that occasionally the security check and passport control lines can get pretty long, so you really should be at the actual airport at least 2 hours before the flight, perhaps a little more.